# Ajuda com Update de formulario web

Tags: php, mysql, sql, aplicação-web, crud

Estou desenvolvendo uma sistema de CRUD, e estou com problemas para atualizar usuários cadastrados. O ruim é que meu navegador não mostra nenhum erro.

O problema é que quando faço edição em algum campo, por exemplo, email, onde estava escrito joao@j.com. Digito joao@joao12.com. Quando clico no botão o campo email volta a ficar joao@j.com, e não aparece nenhuma mensagem de erro e nem volta para a pagina home.php.

O correto seria deixar o campo email preenchido com joao@joao12.com e voltar para pagina home.php.

Segue abaixo o código com a pagina de edição de usuário.

Desde já agradeço a ajuda de vocês!

Pra melhor visualização do código, coloquei no PasteBin:
http://pastebin.com/kAe9vHpv

Desde já agradeço a ajuda de vocês!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cara, problema beeem simples, ele não esta entrando na condição do _POST porque o name="'atualizar'" está com duas aspas:

```
<button class="btn waves-effect waves-light" type="submit" name="'atualizar'">
```

troca por:

```
<button class="btn waves-effect waves-light" type="submit" name="atualizar">
```

Comment: Nossa cara, era isso mesmo O_o
Obrigado pela ajuda e pelo bom olho! haha

Comment: sim, muitas vezes é o erro menos óbvio... @Gabriel